# SQL Top Function with a clustered index

Tags: t-sql

The order that the records come in is not always guaranteed unless I use an `order by` clause.

If I throw a clustered index on a table and then do a `select top 100`, for example, would the 100 rows returned always be the same?

I am asking this because a clustered index sorts the data physically on the key value.

I am lead to believe so from my observations, but wanted to see what others thought.

Comment: No it is not guaranteed. Simple scenario: parallel execution

Comment: **[No Seatbelt – Expecting Order without ORDER BY](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)**

Comment: A Clustered index results in the pages stored to be ordered; that doesn't mean when the data engine reads those pages, and returns data from them, it'll be in the same order.

Comment: And another one, with links to more articles inside: [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The rule is simple:  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  The only exception is a result set associated with a query that has an `ORDER BY` in the outermost `SELECT`.

A clustered index affects how data is stored on each page.  However, it does not *guarantee* that a result set built on that table will even use the clustered index.

Consider a table that has a primary, clustered key on `id` and a query that returns:

```
select top (100) othercol
from t;
```

This query could use an index on `othercol` -- avoiding the clustered index altogether.